# How to link to headers on websites that don't have id?

Tags: web-apps, hyperlink

On some websites, you can easily link to a section of the page that starts with some heading. For example, to link to the section "Site creation process" of the Wikipedia article "Stack Exchange", you can use a link like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#Site_creation_process.

On other pages, this is not possible, because the HTML elements that represent headings of the article don't have the `id` attribute. For example, there is no way to link to the section "Replaced by computers" of the BBC article "The end of middle management?" No link like http://www.bbc.com/capital/story/20150624-the-end-of-middle-management#replaced-by-computers or anything similar will do the right thing and jump to the correct heading.

But I believe a web app might be able to fix this. I imagine having URL like http://thewebapp.com/section_link?url=http://www.bbc.com/capital/story/20150624-the-end-of-middle-management&section=Replaced_by_computers (or http://thewebapp.com/short_link/abcdef) which would somehow link to the section of the specified web page.

Does such a web application exist?

I'm looking for a web application, because I want to send the link to others and have it just work. So a Greasemonkey user script, or a browser extension wouldn't work for me.

Comment: Anchors are processed in the browser, so that would require JavaScript to be injected. I very much doubt such a webapp can exists (except if it retrieves the full page and presents it itself). A userscript for that however does exist: [AutoTOC](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/1301) is what I use, and it works fine.

Comment: @Izzy - Unfortunately that will not work for the example given as the "heading" is not tagged as such - it uses `<p><em>...` rather than `<Hx>..` *poor authoring I know* and AutoTOC works by identifying `<H...` tags.

Comment: @SteveBarnes Ouch. OK, in that case I very much doubt any solution does exist – except for burning that "designer" and have somebody writing "clean code"...

Comment: Maybe pushing it through an online app that auto IDs each paragraph & header on the page then you could send a tag, or a short tag, of the format `http:url_of_auto_id?url_of_original#generated_id` but off the top of my head I don't know of such a service currently running.

Comment: https://www.urbaninsight.com/2013/07/15/paragraph-level-search-results-solr discusses doing almost exactly what is needed here.

Comment: There was a proposal, http://zesty.ca/crit/draft-yee-url-textsearch-00.txt to provide exactly what you are asking for back in 1998 but AFAIK no browser has implemented it.